# Emulator not working and it shows "ko:Could not create temp file for system partition image: %s,size=0x%llx" when i click on run..somebody help me

Tags: android, eclipse

Emulator not working and it shows.

> ```
> "ko:Could not create temp file for system partition image: %s,size=0x%llx" 
>   when i click on run.
> ```

my emulator detail shown as below;

> ```
> Name: NexusOne
> CPU/ABI: ARM(armeabi-v7a)
> target: Android 4.4.2(API level 19)
> Skin: HVGA
> SD Card: 512M
>
> hw.dPad: no
> hw.accelerometer: yes
> hw.device.name: Nexus One
> vm.heapSize: 32
> skin.dynamic: no
> hw.device.manufacturer: Google
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: @GregtheIncredulous they don't allow me to post photobecause im new. but i've tried all the other people posted in stackoverflow like give the permission to temp file and hardware section choose host GPU but still couldnt work.

Comment: I've been trying to solve this for months now! This is the first result on my google search and there is absolutely nothing here. It's sad.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem on windows. I solved it running cmd as administrator

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem too. To fix it, just run Android Studio as administrator.